# SD card initialisation; acmd41 fails;

Tags: embedded, sd-card

I'm trying to init sd card and never get card ready.

In details:

There are dev board with a chip with a SD Host controller and micro SDHC UHS-1 card.

Init sequence I'm following:

- cmd0: arg `0x00`. That is fine
- cmd8: arg `0x1AA`. Fine, 0x1aa is returned back.
- acmd41: 
  -- first cmd55: arg `0x00`. Fine, response `0x120` indicates that 'app_cmd' flag is set.
  -- second cmd41: arg `0x5100'0000` (HCS: 1; XPC: 1; S18R: 1 - SDHC/SDXC supported; Maximum performance; Switch to 1.8V respectively) 
  Response is `0xff8000`. So that seems to be a valid OCR, supporting a whole voltages range.

Once OCR supported by a card is known I send ACMD41 again with a set OCR: 
-- cmd55: arg `0x00`. valid `0x120` response.
-- cmd41: arg `0x51ff'80000`. 
In this case I always get `0xffff'ffff` from a card which is not a proper respond by any means even though SD Host controller do not indicate any errors like timeout or wrong CRC, so that seems that card indeed sends that value.

Repeating described above acmd41 (cmd55 + cmd41) continue to return the same response, cmd55 is fine, cmd41 is `0xffffffff`

Any ideas what is going wrong/I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: What platform are you running? What are the utilities you're using? You're missing so many necessary details here.

Comment: @ifconfig what do you mean by 'utilities'? and what details do you think are missed?

Comment: @ifconfig, I'm initialising sd card, there is no OS. And I don't know how OS is relevant to SD Card Specification. Is anything else in 'everything' list should be disclosed?

Comment: Then on _what_ platform are you working? Arduino? Embedded Linux? What?

Comment: "no OS" literally means neither 'embedded' or any other sort of Linux, windows, mac os, ios or android...

Comment: @ifconfig The OP gave enough information for us to think about the problem. There is no OS involved, the utilities are irrelevant, s/he told us each command and its argument as well as the response between host and card. If I had time (I'm at work) I would look up the SD card specification to re-check commands and responses, and the command sequences. But perhaps some other embedded specialist jumps in.

Comment: Okay, I suppose I'm just missing something here. Please answer, I am curious to see what this is about.

Comment: Have a look:https://www.microchip.com/forums/m452739.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly, card init sequence is fine. That's a hardware issue.

Power supplying to a card was screwed, so card didn't have enough power for a proper work but somehow got enough to send a responds.

To make things even more interesting out of a few cards I tried:

- one card didn't work at all
- one failed at initialisation (as described above)
- and one did everything but stayed in 'Programming' state indefinitely when attempted to write data.

Thanks for everyone :)